# Construct ID string from components including first and last letters from names

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am working on an Excel document and I need help with a formula. My sheet is set up so:

```
Column A = First Names
Column B = Last Names
Column G = User ID
```

I need the user ID to be in this format: AOKxxxx01 where, in order:

```
x = first letter of first name
x = last letter of first name
x = first letter of last name
x = last letter of last name
```

So for `Bob Smith` the user ID would appear as `AOKBBSH01` in Column G.

The first `B` is the first letter of first name, the second `B` is the last letter of first name, the `S` is the first letter of last name, the `H` is the last letter of last name. The surrounding `AOK` and `01` are constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
="AOK"&LEFT(A2)&UPPER(RIGHT(A2))&LEFT(B2)&UPPER(RIGHT(B2))&"01"
```

Comment: Thank you!! The only thing is when I copy the formula down the last 2 numbers should stay as "01" and they are going in numerical order.. 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, ect.